# configurable sequence of Integer numbers

Tags: python, random, distribution

0I want to generate a random sequence of Integer numbers that I can somehow configure. I want the sequence to be configurable in terms of frequencies of appearance of certain numbers and the spacing between every two consecutive appearances. The numbers in my sequence are within a determined range. The idea is I want to have different sequences that have some patterns in them since I am interested in analyzing the impact of the pattern itself when taken as input for another program I wrote.

could you please direct me to where I can find algorithms that can help me with this? I searched online, all I found is uniform distributions which is not what I want in this case.

here I have the code I have for just my basic referential sequence but I don't know how to move from here.

```
import random
from random import randint
f= open('Sequence.txt' , 'w+')
random.seed()
NumberOfVar = random.randint(10000, 100000)
random.seed(3)
NumberOfLines = random.randint(10000, 50000000)
for Iterator in range(0, NumberOfLines):
    Var = random.randint(0, NumberOfVar)
    S = str(Var )+ "\n"
    f.write(S)
f.close()
```

thank you

Comment: You defining the frequency of something seems contradictory to random... Also, show you have made an attempt at this by showing code instead of asking others to do it for you.

Comment: I am not asking for code!!! I am asking about known and commonly used algorithms for non-uniform distributions.

Comment: Your question is fairly vague, leaving out important details. For example, do you want all integer values to be possible or are the values to be constrained between two integers? And so on. Please give a *specific example* to narrow things down. After that, you can explain how you want the problem to be generalized. Also, show some of your own work on the problem, preferably as code but other kinds of attempts may be suitable. Finally, requests for resources (such as libraries) outside this site are explicitly off-topic, so please delete that part of your question.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more details. thank you for your remarks.

Comment: You can choose the frequencies with `random.choices` (python 3.6+) and guarantee spacing with [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind that we don't know your requirements in detail:

I would be tempted to generate the sequence one number at a time. You can change the parameters of the generation based on the state of the sequence up to that point, skewing the generation and rejecting values as appropriate.

numpy's [`random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) has a probability distribution parameter that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to select from a bin.  For example, if you wanted twice as many odd numbers as even, then your bin would look like: `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, ...]`  Select from the bin, either with or without replacement as you want.

Of course, constructing the right bin might be complex for some requirements.